# Django REST Framework Serializando modelos que tienen campos/relaciones ForeignKey y ManyToManyFields

Tags: python, django-models, djangorestframework, serialización

**El reto de esta pregunta es claro a partir de la actualización 2 que es el estado actual de la misma, se puede leer completa para entender su contexto si se desea**

:)

Tengo el siguiente modelo que deseo serializar para exponerlo via REST

```
class RehabilitationSession(models.Model):

    patient = models.ForeignKey('userprofiles.PatientProfile', null=True, blank=True,verbose_name='Paciente', related_name='patientprofile')

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    medical = models.ForeignKey('userprofiles.MedicalProfile', null=True, blank=True,
                            verbose_name='Médico tratante')
    therapist = models.ForeignKey('userprofiles.TherapistProfile', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Terapeuta')


    date_session_begin = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), verbose_name = 'Fecha de inicio')

    upper_extremity = MultiSelectField(
    max_length=255,
    choices=EXTREMITY_CHOICES,
    blank=False,
    verbose_name='Extremidad Superior'
)

    affected_segment = models.ManyToManyField(AffectedSegment,verbose_name='Segmento afectado')
    movement = ChainedManyToManyField(
    Movement, #Modelo encadenado
    chained_field = 'affected_segment',
    chained_model_field = 'corporal_segment_associated',
    verbose_name='Movimiento'
)

    metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metric, blank=True, verbose_name='Métrica')
    date_session_end = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), verbose_name = 'Fecha de finalización')
    period = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True, verbose_name='Tiempo de duración de la sesión')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Sesiones de Rehabilitación'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.patient
```

Para serializar los campos que son Foreingkey, [me estoy basando en esta documentación de REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield).

Mi archivo serializers.py es este:

```
from .models import RehabilitationSession
from rest_framework import serializers

class RehabilitationSessionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

patient = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='patientprofile',)

class Meta:
    model = RehabilitationSession
    fields = ('url','id','patient',
              'date_session_begin','status','upper_extremity',

              'date_session_end', 'period','games','game_levels',
              'iterations','observations',)
```

Estoy utilizando [HyperlinkedIdentityField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield) debido a que mi modelo es serializado con HyperlinkedModelSerializer, pero no me queda claro como lo debo serializar acorde a las opciones que allí se dan. Se dice que `HyperlinkedIdentityField` también puede ser utilizado sobre un atributo del objeto, y la idea es que en la vista de mi api cuando el modelo quede serializado, me muestre el url de ese campo, que es una instancia del modelo PatientProfile, es decir un registro de un paciente.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Mi archivo principal `urls.py` en donde incluyo las rutas para determinar las urls es:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include #patterns
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import home, home_files

# REST Framework packages
from rest_framework import routers
from userprofiles.views import UserViewSet, GroupViewSet, PatientProfileViewSet
from medical_encounter_information.views import RehabilitationSessionViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'rehabilitation-session', RehabilitationSessionViewSet)
router.register(r'patientprofile', PatientProfileViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),

    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),

    url(r'^', include('userprofiles.urls')),
    #Call the userprofiles/urls.py

    url(r'^', include('medical_encounter_information.urls' )),
    #Call the medical_encounter_information/urls.py

    #  which is a regular expression that takes the desired urls and passes as an argument
    # the filename, i.e. robots.txt or humans.txt.
    url(r'^(?P<filename>(robots.txt)|(humans.txt))$',
        home_files, name='home-files'),

    #REST Frameworks url's
    # Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
    # Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.

    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]
```

Cuando intento acceder al url de mi api rest de dicho modelo, obtengo el siguiente mensaje en mi consola:

```
    File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/neurorehabilitation_projects_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 355, in to_representation
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % self.view_name)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "patientprofile". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
[08/Mar/2016 16:05:45] "GET /api/rehabilitation-session/ HTTP/1.1" 500 165647
```

Y en mi navegador esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo serializar un campo ForeignKey?
Les agradezco su ayuda.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2**

He querido probar utilizando las relaciones anidadas como me han sugerido en este post, dado que también sería bueno tener en la serialización de mi modelo en este caso sesión de rehabilitación, los campos propios del paciente de esa sesión, del médico de esa sesión y del terapeuta de esa sesión y no sus urls respectivos que me lleve a los datos de ellos mismos, para efectos de usabilidad y me imagino para lectura de alguna aplicación tercera, aunque me imagino tambien que por el url se puede tambien acceder a los valores y llaves del json de cada url ¿verdad?

Bueno, en este momento, los tengo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder organizar mis datos de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/rehabilitation-session/9/",
    "id": 9,
    "patient": [
        {'id' : 1, 'full_name' : 'Andres Enfermizo',
         'diagnostic' : 'Diabetes', 'time_of_evolution' : '3 months'
        },      
    "medical": [
        {'id' : 1, 'full_name' : 'Doctor House',
         'specialty' : 'Epidemiologist', 'xperience' : '23 years'
        } ,
    ]
    "therapist": [
        {'id' : 1, 'full_name' : 'Christian',
         'specialty' : 'Legs', 'xperience' : '13 years'
        } ,
    ]
    "affected_segment": [
        {'id' : 1, 'affected_segment' : 'shoulder',
         'damage' : '30%', 'time_of_retrieve' : '10 months'
        } ,

    ],
}
```

Entonces acorde a la documentación, ¿[Nested Relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) o incluso [Custom relational fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) podría servir?

Lo he hecho siguiendo la guia para [Nested Relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) de esta forma, por ahora solo para el caso de mostrar de manera anidada los datos del paciente en la serializacion de la sesión de rehabilitación:

Serializando  el modelo `PatientProfile`:

```
class PatientProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PatientProfile
        fields = ('url','id','user','full_name','time_of_evolution','diagnostic','marital_status','educational_level','partner_full_name','partner_relationship','partner_phone','partner_gender',
                  'care_provider',)
```

La vista `PatientProfileViewset` que expondrá el modelo serializado

```
class PatientProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PatientProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PatientProfileSerializer
```

Ahora serializo mi modelo `RehabilitationSession`:

```
class RehabilitationSessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    patient = PatientProfileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = RehabilitationSession
        fields = ('url','id','patient',
                  #'affected_segment',
                  'date_session_begin','status','upper_extremity',

                  'date_session_end', 'period','games','game_levels',
                  'iterations','observations',)
```

La vista `RehabilitationSessionViewSet` que expondrá el modelo serializado

```
class RehabilitationSessionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RehabilitationSession.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RehabilitationSessionSerializer
```

Y estos son mis router's para cada modelo serializado para accederlos por url en el navegador. Están en mi urls.py principal:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include #patterns
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import home, home_files

# REST Framework packages
from rest_framework import routers
from userprofiles.views import (UserViewSet, GroupViewSet, PatientProfileViewSet,)

from medical_encounter_information.views import (RehabilitationSessionViewSet,)


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'rehabilitation-session', RehabilitationSessionViewSet)
router.register(r'patientprofile', PatientProfileViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    ...
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]
```

Obtengo este mensaje al momento de ingresar al url http://localhost:8000/api/rehabilitation-session/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier orientación sera altamente agradecida. :)

Comment: ¿Existe la ruta para `patientprofile` en tus urls.py?

Comment: @César Acabo de poner una actualización de mi archivo principal `urls.py` que es en donde defino las rutas  (`router`'s) para cada vista expuesta que trae consigo cada modelo serializado.

Comment: @César veo que en la documentación [dice lo siguiente:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield)  `view_name - The view name that should be used as the target of the relationship. If you're using the standard router classes this will be a string with the format <model_name>-detail.`

Comment: Entonces en vista de ello he cambiado mi clase `RehabilitationSessionSerializer` en su propiedad `view_name` del atributo al que le aplico `HyperlinkedIdentityField` con un valor al formato `<model_name>-detail`

Comment: MI clase quedo asi: `class RehabilitationSessionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    patient = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='patientprofile-detail',)
    #affected_segment = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='affectedsegment-detail',)
    class Meta: ...` y de esta forma me funciono la serializacion del campo `patient` que es `ForeignKey`  https://cldup.com/T1Vy7p5kjA.png

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, porque tambien se me habia pasado el detalle de serializar el modelo de `PatientProfile` y ponerlo en mis `route`'s

Comment: Perfecto! Publica tu propia respuesta y luego cierras las pregunta para que no quede abierda. Saludos

Comment: @César he puesto una segunda actualización llamada ** ACTUALIZACIÓN 2 ** en donde planteo una nueva inquietud acorde a la serialización de datos de manera anidada que nos planteaba el compañero  aquí en la respuesta que me dio. Cualquier ayuda les agradezco mucho. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente, para el caso de obtener de manera anidada los datos en mi respuesta en el (los) documento(s) JSON's que mi api genera con `django-rest-framework`, he optado por la siguiente solución:

Retomo desde el inicio para dar una descripción de lo realizado, por lo que empezaré por mostrar cuales son mis modelos definidos originalmente, como los serializé, como se generan las vistas o endpoints y finalmente como se establecen las rutas (`router's`) para exponerlos tipo `URLConf`

Estos son mis modelos definidos

**1.**`PatientProfile` model, definido `userprofiles/models.py`

```
class PatientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    time_of_evolution = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    diagnostic = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Usuarios con perfil de pacientes'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

**2.**`MedicalProfile` model definido en `userprofiles/models.py`

```
class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Usuarios con perfil de médicos'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

**3.**`TherapistProfile` definido en `userprofiles/models.py`

```
class TherapistProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Usuarios con perfil de terapeutas'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

**Serializando**

La serialización de estos modelos la tengo de esta forma en `userprofiles/serializers.py`

```
from .models import PatientProfile, MedicalProfile, TherapistProfile
from rest_framework import serializers

class PatientProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = PatientProfile
            fields = ('url','id','user','full_name','time_of_evolution','diagnostic','marital_status','educational_level','partner_full_name','partner_relationship','partner_phone','partner_gender',
                      'care_provider',)

class MedicalProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = MedicalProfile
            fields = ('url','id','user','full_name','specialty')
    
class TherapistProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = TherapistProfile
            fields = ('url','id','user','full_name','specialty')
```

Las vistas que exponen como `endpoints` los modelos serializados anteriores estan dadas en `userprofiles/views.py` de esta forma:

```
from .models import PatientProfile, MedicalProfile, TherapistProfile
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import (PatientProfileSerializer, MedicalProfileSerializer, TherapistProfileSerializer,)

class PatientProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PatientProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PatientProfileSerializer

class MedicalProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MedicalProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MedicalProfileSerializer

class TherapistProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TherapistProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TherapistProfileSerializer
```

Presento el modelo `RehabilitationSessions` localizado en medical_encounter_information/models.py el cual tiene tres llaves foráneas a los anteriores perfiles de usuarios `PatientProfile` , `MedicalProfile` y `TherapistProfile`

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedManyToManyField
from django.utils import timezone

from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class RehabilitationSession(models.Model):

    EXTREMITY_CHOICES = (
        ('Extremidad superior derecha', 'Superior Derecha'),
        ('Extremidad superior izquierda', 'Superior Izquierda'),
    )

    # Primer campo con ForeignKey relationship 
    patient = models.ForeignKey('userprofiles.PatientProfile',      null=True, blank=True,                                verbose_name='Paciente', related_name='patientprofile')
    
    # Segundo campo con ForeignKey relationship 
    medical = models.ForeignKey('userprofiles.MedicalProfile', null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name='Médico tratante', related_name='medicalprofile')

    # Tercer campo con ForeignKey relationship
    therapist = models.ForeignKey('userprofiles.TherapistProfile', null=True, blank=True,
                               verbose_name='Terapeuta')


    date_session_begin = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), verbose_name = 'Fecha de inicio')
  
    upper_extremity = MultiSelectField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=EXTREMITY_CHOICES,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='Extremidad Superior'
    )

    affected_segment = models.ManyToManyField(AffectedSegment,verbose_name='Segmento afectado', related_name='affectedsegment')
    movement = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Movement, #Modelo encadenado
        chained_field = 'affected_segment',
        chained_model_field = 'corporal_segment_associated',
        verbose_name='Movimiento'
    )

    metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metric, blank=True, verbose_name='Métrica')
    date_session_end = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), verbose_name = 'Fecha de finalización')
    period = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True, verbose_name='Tiempo de duración de la sesión')

    observations = models.TextField(blank=False, verbose_name='Observaciones')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Sesiones de Rehabilitación'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.patient
```

La serialización de los campos de la clase `RehabilitationSession` esta dada por la clase `RehabilitationSessionSerializer` localizada en `medical_encounter_information/serializers.py`

Es aqui en donde tenia mis dudas acerca de como realizar la serializacion y para lo cual estaba consultando un poco [acerca de como se manejan las relaciones en Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

[Encontré en la documentación como trabajar la serialización de manera anidada](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) sin la necesidad de recurrir a clases extras del tipo [Serializer Relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#serializer-relations).

La clave está en adicionar un campo llamado `depth` el cual permite de manera recursiva n niveles de profundidad (no se realmente hasta que número determinado de niveles) para poder serializar los subdocumentos JSON que tengamos, en este caso los que traía cada `ForeignKey` de cada perfil de usuario necesitado en una sesión de rehabilitación (`PatientProfile`,`MedicalProfile`, `TherapistProfile`)

[Aquí](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) dice lo siguiente:

> The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a flat representation.
>
> If you want to customize the way the serialization is done you'll need to define the field yourself.

Entonces mi clase `RehabilitationSessionSerializer` queda asi:

```
from .models import (RehabilitationSession,) 
from rest_framework import serializers
class RehabilitationSessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RehabilitationSession
        fields = ('url','id','patient','medical','therapist','affected_segment','movement','metrics','date_session_begin',
                  'status','slug', 'date_session_end','period','games','game_levels',
                  'iterations','observations',)
        #read_only_fields = ('patient','medical','therapist',)
        depth=1
```

La vista `ViewSet` que expone esta serialización esta dada de esta forma en `medical_encounter_information/views.py`

```
from .models import RehabilitationSession
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import (RehabilitationSessionSerializer,)

class RehabilitationSessionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RehabilitationSession.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RehabilitationSessionSerializer
```

Mis rutas/routers en urls.py para el acceso a los modelos expuestos via rest framework son:

```
from rest_framework import routers
from userprofiles.views import PatientProfileViewSet,                 MedicalProfileViewSet, TherapistProfileViewSet

from medical_encounter_information.views import (RehabilitationSessionViewSet, AffectedSegmentViewSet, MovementViewSet,
                                                 MetricViewSet,)

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
# Because we're using viewsets instead of views, we can automatically
# generate the URL conf for our API, by simply registering the viewsets with a router class.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'rehabilitationsession', RehabilitationSessionViewSet)
router.register(r'patientprofile', PatientProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'medicalprofile', MedicalProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'therapistprofile', TherapistProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'affectedsegment', AffectedSegmentViewSet)
router.register(r'movement', MovementViewSet)
router.register(r'metrics', MetricViewSet)



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    
    url(r'^', include('userprofiles.urls')),
    #Call the userprofiles/urls.py

    url(r'^', include('medical_encounter_information.urls' )),
    #Call the medical_encounter_information/urls.py

    #REST Frameworks url's
    # Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
    # Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.

    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    # Including default login and logout views for use with the browsable API.
    # That's optional, but useful if your API requires authentication and you want to use the browsable API.
    # Note that the URL path can be whatever you want, but you must include 'rest_framework.urls' with the 'rest_framework' namespace.
    # You may leave out the namespace in Django 1.9+, and REST framework will set it for you.
]
```

Es entonces que cuando consulto este API en mi navegador, el modelo `RehabilitationSession` que posee las tres claves foráneas a los modelos `PatientProfile`, `MedicalProfile` y `TherapistProfile`; al ser serializado me queda desplegado de la siguiente manera con los documentos de los respectivos perfiles de usuario mencionados, anidados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es así como pude tener una serialización de varios modelos en una misma vista por asi decirlo.

POr supuesto existen varias clases como las de [Serialization relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#serializer-relations) que permiten manejar las relaciones entre modelos en django rest framework acorde a lo que necesitemos, si es una url, si es un string, si es un campo de tipo slug o si es un campo tipo PrimaryKey o si es anidado como lo que necesitaba

[También encontré este ejemplo de serialización anidada](http://voorloopnul.com/blog/representing-hierarchical-data-with-django-rest-framework/) o recursiva para campos, pero en esta ocasión se trata de un mismo modelo, interesante y muy necesario, para un ejemplo muy común en web que es el de comentarios y respuestas a esos mismos comentarios.

Quiero darles también muchas gracias por las ideas y orientaciones, me fueron útiles para buscar mi solución :D

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza [Nested Relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Por ejemplo:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

donde **tracks** del modelos **Album** es una clave foránea al modelo **Track**.

Comment: probé con Nested Relationships como me recomendaste, pero me sale este error `File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/neurorehabilitation_projects_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  614.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/rehabilitation-session/
Exception Value: 'PatientProfile' object is not iterable`

Comment: Puedes poner el código?

Comment: he puesto una segunda actualización llamada ** ACTUALIZACIÓN 2 ** en donde planteo una nueva inquietud acorde a la serialización de datos de manera anidada que planteaba DJeanCar aquí. Cualquier ayuda les agradezco mucho. :)

Answer (score 1):

Cuidado con las relaciones anidadas, son un *kill performance* para tu API, hablo de ello en este post: http://miguelgomez.io/python/optimizando-django-rest-framework/

Por otro lado, utilizaría la clase `MethodSerializers` para crear los serializadores lo más personalizado posible.

Un saludo.

Comment: MIguel, muchas gracias, interesante el enfoque, y si, asumo que la transaccionalidad y la conversión de los datos de formato que hará DRF, la cosa a nivel de rendimiento se complica. TOmaré en cuenta tu recomendación para mejorar mi API en este sentido. :D